# Getting Monitor resolution in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, monitor, resolution

Is there a equatable bit of code to GetSystemMetrics in win32api, for Ubuntu?  I need to get the monitors width and height in pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're a GUI toolkit. Why else would you be interested in the screen dimensions?

Check out `gtk.gdk.screen_width()` and `gtk.gdk.screen_height()` from PyGTK. Something similar should be available for QT.

Comment: With wxPython, it would be the GetDisplaySize method: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/wxFunctions.html?highlight=getdisplaysize#GetDisplaySize

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently re-configuring some of my programs to run in Ubuntu. I'm switching out all the Win specific functions.

Answer (score 8):

I can suggest a few approaches that can be used. I have not used the xlib version though.

1) xlib ( X client library for Python programs), if available on your system. You can look at "Display" methods and properties : [python-xlib.sourceforge](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_16.html#SEC15)

2) On Ubuntu, you could do the following to get the screen resolution:

```
   xrandr  | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4
```

3) You can use subprocess python module, to run the above command and extract the information

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen('xrandr | grep "\*" | cut -d" " -f4',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print output
```

Let me know, if this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess


def get_screen_resolution():
    output = subprocess.Popen('xrandr | grep "\*" | cut -d" " -f4',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    resolution = output.split()[0].split(b'x')
    return {'width': resolution[0], 'height': resolution[1]}

print(get_screen_resolution())
```

The `resolution[0]` would be Byte format like b'1020'. To convert this to Integer format, please try `int(resolution[0].decode('UTF-8'))`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and had the same problem. I wanted to solve it without having to rely on extra modules because they aren't installed by default.

So I imagined this small function, which uses xrandr to get the data.

```
def monitorsInfo():

import subprocess

def getParenthesis(texte):
    content = None
    p1 = texte.find('(')
    if p1 >= 0:
        p2 = texte.find(')')
        if p2 > p1:
            content = texte[p1:p2+1]
    return content

commande = ['xrandr','--listmonitors']
res = subprocess.check_output(commande, shell=True).decode().split('\n')

monitors = {}

for l in res:
    if len(l) > 1:
        if l[0] != ' ':
            if l.split()[0] == l.split()[0].upper():

                options = getParenthesis(l)
                if options:
                    l = l.replace(options, '')
                z = l.split()

                # this is a connector
                name = z[0]
                conn = None
                primary = None
                geo = None
                size = None
                width = height = offsetx = offsety = None
                if z[1].lower() == 'connected':
                    conn = True
                    # monitor in use :-)
                else:
                    # screeen connection exists, no screen used
                    conn = False
                # for connected screens : get extra data
                if conn:
                    if z[2].lower() == 'primary':
                        primary = True
                        z.pop(2)
                    # other data for connected screeens
                    geo = z[2]   # get rid of extra 'primary'
                    size = ''.join(z[3:])
                    # get width and height
                    z = geo.split('+')
                    offsetx = int(z[1])
                    offsety = int(z[2])
                    z = z[0].split('x')
                    width = int(z[0])
                    height = int(z[1])


                # create a dict per monitor
                d = {}
                d['name'] = name
                d['connected'] = conn
                d['primary'] = primary
                d['geometry'] = geo
                d['options'] = options
                d['size'] = size
                d['width'] = width
                d['height'] = height
                d['offsetx'] = offsetx
                d['offsety'] = offsety

                monitors[name] = d

return monitors
```

The result is returned as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[pyautogui](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html) makes the work simple.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.size()
```

will fetch your screen resolution as a tuple containing (width, height)

Comment: This is the true cross-platform solution (will work on Windows, Linux and MacOS)

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this with Python 3 - you can use the `Xlib` module:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
screen = Display(':0').screen()
print(screen.width_in_pixels, screen.height_in_pixels)
```

Homepage: https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib

---

If you don't have the `Xlib` module installed, run

```
python3 -m pip install Xlib
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-xlib
```