# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api' in Ubuntu

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to run a python code there is an error in this line of code: from win32api import GetSystemMetrics  # gets your computer's resolution size

Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

how can I fix it in ubuntu?

Comment: You cannot use Windows APIs to access system information on Ubuntu. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3597965/9568847) has multiple answers on how to get your screen resolution on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32api` and all of the `win32` packages are only installable on a Windows system.